# (Android) How to cancel default system behaviours/events

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi, wifi-direct

How can you register for certain system events and cancel the default action that the system would normally do when these events happen. e.g at certain times, the system shows an ugly native UI for when it detects new WIFI Access points. How can you kill that System UI and display something specific to your application in one of your fancy-looking activities.

Anyone care to share some knowledge on this.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly and you just want your ui changed check this application out
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.shekeen.WidgetHolder&hl=en

Cause you really don't need to kill the operation you just want to change how it looks/shows up.

Or maybe this if you want a widget
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.vineetsirohi.customwidget&hl=en